# AADSTS50011: The redirect URI mismatch error with HTTP

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-business-central

From our Business central test environment, we are trying to communicate to Azure AD. So while giving grant consent it is trying to authenticate but finally getting this error

[image]

I tried to copy-paste the URL in AD but got this error

[image]

I don't know how to change to HTTPS in Business central side

Comment: Try using **Mobile and desktop applications** platform by selecting default redirect URI: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`. Check if this helps https://www.kauffmann.nl/2022/02/23/configuring-business-central-for-azure-active-directory-authentication-and-oauth-2/

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, Azure AD (Entra) application cannot be registered with an HTTP URI, so your production instance (if you use on-premises BC) must be accessed via HTTPS. But for testing purposes, http://localhost will do the trick. Keep the URI as it is, just replace the server name with "localhost".